# GitHub Coptilot does not work in vscode when editing Python

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, github-copilot

I can run python scripts (.py) inside vs code, and CoPilot works fine with Powershell scripts (.ps1), however, I'm not getting any Github Copilot suggestions. The Copilot icon shows and the plugin appear to be activated.

**GitHub Copilot**: v1.58.7236

**VsCode**
Version: 1.73.0 (user setup)
Commit: 8fa188b2b301d36553cbc9ce1b0a146ccb93351f
Date: 2022-11-01T15:34:06.111Z
Electron: 19.0.17
Chromium: 102.0.5005.167
Node.js: 16.14.2
V8: 10.2.154.15-electron.0
OS: Windows_NT x64 10.0.19045
Sandboxed: No

Any ideas?

[image]

Video of running Github Copilot for js (working) and trying to run Github Copilot for python: https://vimeo.com/769046582/09e2756f17

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure if upgrading vscode or if I simply didn't do it right before.
However, it appears that Github Copilot is now (always was?) triggered by the tab or space key.

Version: 1.73.1 (user setup)
Commit: 6261075646f055b99068d3688932416f2346dd3b
Date: 2022-11-09T04:27:29.066Z
Electron: 19.0.17
Chromium: 102.0.5005.167
Node.js: 16.14.2
V8: 10.2.154.15-electron.0
OS: Windows_NT x64 10.0.19045
Sandboxed: No

Answer (score 1):

Are you able to hover your mouse over the comment and get suggestions? Also, try restarting and making sure you have the latest version